# Database design for hashtags in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

Im currently working on system that will enable to use of hashtags on our site and im having some trouble with how to best and most efficiently store the hashtags in the database. The design needs to be set up so that its relatively simple to retrieve posts that match search terms (like on Twitter when you click the link of a hashtag and it shows all the tweets with that hashtag).
The hashtags will be stored in db by extracting the terms from the content of created posts (also comparable to twitter) and inserting them. How is insert them of course is the problem at hand:
At the moment I'm torn between 2 possible designs:

1) My first design idea (and perhaps more conventional) is a 3-table design:

- the first table simply stores the post content and other data related
  to the post itself (im already using a table like this).
- the second table simply stores new hashtags being used, basically functioning as a look-up for all hashtags that have been used.
- the third table is a table that defines the relationships between hashtags and posts. So basically is would be a simple table that
  would have one column with the ID of a post and another column for
  the ID of a single hashtag that we stored in the previous table. So a post that has for example 3 hashtags would have 3 rows in this table, 1 for each hashtag with which it is associated.

2) The second design is 2-table design:

- the same table with the post data stored in it, like above.
- the 2nd table is a mix of the 2nd and 3rd table in the first design: It holds the data between the relationships of hashtags and
  posts, but instead of storing the new hashtag in a table assigning it
  an ID, it simply stores the actual hashtag (so for example "#test")
  itself along with the ID of the post. Same concept applies here that
  if a post has 3 hashtags in it, it would store 3 individual rows in
  the table.

The reason I'm torn between the ideas, is because the first option does seem to the more standard way to do it and there seems to be more "structure" to it. Since they are hashtags, however, I don't see a lot of purpose in actually assigning a unique ID to each hashtag, since hashtags aren't true classifications like a category or genre or so.

Also for when I try to make a search page for hashtags I have to use less JOINs since I wouldn't need to look up the ID of the searched terms and then go to another table and find the associated posts with that ID.

Additionally, when trying to simply list the hashtags of a post, one thing that would be kind of annoying is that the hashtags may print out differently than a user may have stylized them in their post. So for example if a user adds #testing, but another user had previously entered a post with #TeStIng, the hashtag for the post would then print out #TeStIng, since that's how it would have been saved in the database lookup table.  Of course you could make it case-sensitive but in searches #testing and #TeStIng should be considered the same hashtag so that could get messy. Or am I wrong about this? Does anyone have a suggestion about how to avoid this scenario?

On the other hand my concern with the 2nd table design is that I fear it could become inefficient if the table grows to be huge, since looking up strings is slower than searching for integers (which I would be doing with the first design). However, since I would have to use more JOINs in the 1st design, would there actually be a performance difference? Just to be clear, when searching for strings themselves I would be using the = operator and not LIKE.

Similarly, I would imagine that the first design is more efficient if I wanted to make queries about the hashtags themselves, for example how many posts are using a certain hashtag and things like that, though it would not be very difficult with the 2nd design either, I just wonder about the efficiency again.

Any thoughts on what may work better? The most important thing is that it is efficient to search by hashtag, so for example I'm trying to find posts that have #test associated with them. Ideally, I would also like to be able to retrieve a post's hashtag from the database as it was stylized by the user in the post content. All other queries and functions around analyzing hashtags is secondary at this point.

Comment: Go with the first approach as it'll keep it scalable. Also, for the listing of hashtags with the original formatting, you just need to ensure that the hashtags you display are from the post itself and not from the list table (you can always get the hashtags from the post again)

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AkshatSinghal. Thats what I was thinking too, to just retrieve the original from the post content but is there any efficient way to do this (sql, php or otherwise). since im going to have to filter it out of a block of text, ill probably have to use regex or so and if I do this for a number of posts on one page load I fear about the speed and efficiency. Any thoughts?

Comment: Also any thoughts about the efficiency of having to use an extra JOIN in the query when trying to retrieve posts if I go with the 1st design? Would it be negligible even when the tables become very large?

Comment: @arian1123 for retrieving the original hashtags from the post, you can use the following approach: get string position of the hashtag in the post by searching for the hashtag (keep all hash tags in lower case) in the post (strtolower) and then extract the original hashtag. This would save you from using regex or wildcards.

Comment: Do you really require joins? In case the most common requirement is to get all post for a single hashtag, you can simply get the id of the hashtag from table 2 and search for it in table 3. It'll all be really fast

Comment: @arian1123 just make sure that you set the hashtag (string) as unique key in the table and also keep the hashtags in lower case for ease of searching and standardisation

Comment: @AkshatSinghal thats something to work it to retrieve original terms. As for the joins, you're right I need to make those queries and then still the query that retrieves the post data for each matching post. If I put all of that into query, would I not need to use joins of some sort?

Comment: @arian1123 as Sherif suggested, you can use redis or something similar to store the hashtags and get the id quickly. From the id, it's a really fast query to get the corresponding posts as it would be a foreign key which is indexed by MySQL. Even in case you do not want to use the redis store, you can simply get the id from the db. I'd suggest you do a benchmarking to evaluate whether join would be better than 2 queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Purely from a database normalization perspective your second design would not be in the [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form). There's a reason why you rely on the whole primary and nothing but the key. If anything in the hash table changes that has a direct impact on the post table you come up with a logical inconsistency. For example, the table of hashtags has two rows: one with the hashtag **#politics** and another with the hashtag **#politic**. Let's say the person that created the post for the second hashtags decides to edit their post and updates the hashtag to **#politics** (*perhaps because they made a typo*). Which row do you update?

As for performance, I wouldn't worry about it in the least with the first design. Your database (like almost every major relational dbms out there today) relies on something called a binary search tree (or more specifically a [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)) to optimize the cost of insertion/deletion/search in your database tables when you're properly indexing these values. It can further optimize this with O(1) (*hashtable lookups*) in some text search use cases or you could even do that in a key/value cache store like Memcached/Redis yourself down the road. For the most part, indexing the hashtags in order to create faster search of posts that use those hashtags is definitely the design you want to go for. Since the biggest cost factor isn't in looking up a single hashtag (most searches will have a single hashtag I'm assuming in this use case), but retrieving all of the posts that contain that hashtag.

---

As for addressing the case-insensitive search portion of your query, your dbms most likely has some collation option that you can specify in your schema (like `utf8_general_ci`) where the `ci` represents case-insensitive comparison in the schema. Meaning, the data will be stored as-is, but when compared in a query to another value, MySQL would do the comparison of characters in a case-insensitive manner.

Comment: Excellent answer. Just a question about the case sensitive part: when Im creating the logic that decides whether the to add a new hashtag to the lookup table or if it already exists, if I use `ci` will it register a hashtag if the stylizing is different? so for example would it register both "test" and "Test". If so, it would create 2 different IDs for what is essentially the same hashtag. When I then search the hashtag by name, will it return the 2 IDs, or just 1? And if it does return 2 IDs to match with post is that in any way more inefficient than just searching the 1?

Comment: Yea, the collation only has an effect on how MySQL compares the values, not how it stores them. As for whether or not you wish for the two hashtags to be unique or not is really left up to your design. So, for example it's possible to just store the hashtag in the lookup table in all lowercase form and the post itself will contain the user-submitted data. That way the only purpose of the hashtag table is indexing.

Comment: Think I'll probably lower case all of them. Seems to be reasonable approach. The challenge just becomes an efficient design to extract the hashtags from the post content when trying to just list the hashtags. Good idea to store the some of the ID-name relationships in memcache as well. I will accept this answer.

Comment: Extremely well reasoned @Sherif. Having a single table of all hashtags also allows you to have exceptions table sitting beside it so that typos can be brought together as one entry e.g. yu may want to consolidate the hashtags of  Pampalona Pamplona and Pamps as one tag or have an exclusion table e.g. #1 #2.

Comment: Inmy believe this example for this problem is wrong. In this example we have no update. We have delete and insert.